# '$_SESSION' en wpwngine

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies

Muy buenas tardes a todos, tengo u proyecto en `Wordpress` donde se usan variables *session* de **PHP**, se esta realizando la migracion al servidor `wpengine`, pero dicho servidor no permite *sesiones* **PHP**, he intentado utilizar `setcookie()`, pero tampoco funciona, no se que mas puedo hacer para solucionar este problema y poder salir a producción, este *server* usa *cache* de forma monstruosa, alguien ya ha tenido este problema y lo ha podido solucionar.

Comment: Si la respuesta de Alfabravo no te soluciona el problema, se me ocurre una alternativa que incluye nodejs, se trataría de mantener las sesiones a parte por medio de nodejs y luego he buscado en google y como no, ya existe algo similar: https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

Answer (score 1):

Se supone que se puede usar wp_session de forma muy similar a como se usa `$_SESSION` normalmente. Un ejemplo sería algo como

```
global $wp_session;

$wp_session['cart_items'] = array(
    array(
        'item_id'   => 43,
        'item_name' => 'My Product Name'
    ),
    array(
        'item_id'   => 22,
        'item_name' => 'My Second Product Name'
    )   
);
```

Creo que este [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/) de WordPress te puede ayudar (y es gratis, además).

Referencia externa [aquí](https://pippinsplugins.com/storing-session-data-in-wordpress-without-_session/) (a mayo 3 de 2018)

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, ya he tratado con este plugin pero no me funciona, seteando un valor en un templete y recuperándolo en otro.